# Loading large size model file in web application

Tags: python, machine-learning, gearman

I have created on Machine learning model file in pickle format(~100MB). To get the sentiment analysis result, I have to call that file.

It is not feasible to load this file everytime, so what I was used to do is, I created `Worker` process in `gearman`, which loads this file and stay in listening mode. Like Daemon process

Here is code of gearman, which start  process `call_sentiment_worker` on `4730` port. `self.train' function loads pickle file

```
def __init__(self):
    self.train()
    print "Trained..."
    self.gearman_worker = gearman.GearmanWorker( ['localhost:4730'] )
    self.gearman_worker.register_task('call_sentiment_worker', self.classify_demo)
```

Now in Python 3, gearman is not available.

What is efficient way to handle this situation? It can be alternative of `gearman` or some other technique.

**Edit 1**

Link to code - https://github.com/karimkhanp/sentiment-analysis/blob/2fd8e785f589a00f33dc165551028029151f10bd/without_gearman/sentiment_worker.py

Comment: Deploy that model on flask or grahpipe and run it on a capable machine.

Comment: @YashKumarAtri: I am using `flask`, but it's not feasible or recommended that I load that file every time when I get new request, even if I have capable machine

Comment: moving worker for loading the file outside of python3 application wouldn't be an option?

Comment: @palik: That will complicate the things

Comment: Don't load the model again and again , cache it first before starting flask server and then do inference or better use graphpipe , its much faster for inference.

Comment: @user3449212: Can you put up the inference and model loading code?

Comment: @YashKumarAtri: What you mean by inference? I have added link to my sentiment worker code

Comment: @YashKumarAtri: Is Graphpipe is limited to `TensorFlow, ONNX, and Caffe2 and CNTK`

Comment: Na you can put your custom inference code too. Inference = prediction

Comment: @YashKumarAtri: CAn you give me any reference doc link. Thanks by the way

Comment: this might help https://github.com/oracle/graphpipe-py/issues/7#issuecomment-444432604

Comment: this is how you hit the server from your way `pred = remote.execute(url, X)` url is the usrl where its hosted and X is the data stream for model inference.

Comment: Thanks Yash, this is what I Was looking for

Comment: @YashKumarAtri: Is it necessary to send request parameters in numpy array format?

Comment: Ya looks like it'll take only np array you can only send the feature matrix to it.